# How to validate array in Laravel 5.4

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5, error-handling

How can I validate multiple inputs with same names like:

```
{!! Form::number('amount[]', $item->amount, ['class'=>'form-control width_30', 'placeholder'=>'Amount']) !!}
```

in request?

I only found the method that is used to validate arrays with numbers like

```
{!! Form::number('amount[1]', $item->amount, ['class'=>'form-control width_30', 'placeholder'=>'Amount']) !!}
{!! Form::number('amount[2]', $item->amount, ['class'=>'form-control width_30', 'placeholder'=>'Amount']) !!}
```

but I have to add and delete the field dynamically, so this method won't work for me.

Here is the code of rules in my request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
        'client'=>'required',
        'product'=>'required|array',
        'amount'=>'required|array',
        'item_id' => 'required|array'
    ];
}
```

and when I use this `required|array` method, it returns me an error:

```
ErrorException in HtmlBuilder.php line 65:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\smk\resources\views\admin\sales\edit.blade.php)
```

Comment: did you save array in `$item->amount`? if so, then I guess the problem lies here, `Form::number('field_name', 'default_value')` will expect `default_value` to be a string, and maybe you passed in an array (in `$item->amount`)

Answer (score 0):

just add .* in your validation.

```
public function rules(){
    return ['amount.*'=>'required|array' ];
}
```

Comment: it is not working, laravel still return me this "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"